# Do satellites travel in groups

Tags: amateur-observing

I’m new to this site after googling “do satellites travel in groups”. I read the discussion with posts from 2016 and 2019 and their descriptions did match what we (my wife and I) just witnessed minutes ago.
 I live in Dalhart Texas. We saw the event within 1 hour of sunset. We witnessed at least 15 objects but there could have been many more before we first saw them.
 As the previous comments stated, the objects we saw were also moving NW to SE. No blinking lights, no tell tale red or green lights. Solid light just like countless satellites I have seen before. Same steady pace but all in synchronized direction and speed. Not all were evenly spaced though. As they traveled SE they all slowly dimmed and disappeared all the same point in the sky. This must be the point at which the suns rays no longer reached the “satellites”. These objects appeared in the same relation to the moon as mentioned in a previous comment on this thread. 
 I’m a bit suprised there are so few related sightings posted here. If these “satellites” orbit the earth then there must be countless sightings. 
Thank you for your time

Comment: I found this information via Wikipedia:

Comment: Satellite formation flying is the concept that multiple satellites can work together in a group to accomplish the objective of one larger, usually more expensive, satellite.[1] Coordinating smaller satellites has many benefits over single satellites including simpler designs, faster build times, cheaper replacement creating higher redundancy, unprecedented high resolution, and the ability to view research targets from multiple angles or at multiple times. These qualities make them ideal for astronomy, communications, meteorology, and environmental uses.[2]

Comment: Why this wasn’t explained in the related thread I read here is beyond me. Please refer to Wikipedia for future questions on this subject.

Comment: Trailing formations are formed by multiple satellites orbiting on the same path. Each one follows the previous one separated by a specific time interval to either view a target at different times, or obtain varied viewing angles of the target. Trailing satellites are especially suited for meteorological and environmental applications such as viewing the progress of a fire, cloud formations, and making 3D views of hurricanes. Notable pairs are Landsat 7 with EO-1, the "A-train" consisting of CALIPSO and CloudSat (among others), and Terra with Aqua.

Comment: Usually, these formations are made up of numerous small satellites. A micro satellite weighs under 100 kg and a nano satellite weighs under 10 kg. Magnetosheric Constellation, for instance, would be composed of 100 micro satellites.

Comment: This technology has become more viable thanks to the development of autonomous flying. With an onboard computer and this algorithm, satellites may autonomously position themselves into a formation. Previously, ground control would have to adjust each satellite to maintain formations. Now, satellites may arrive at and maintain formations with faster response time and have the ability to change the formation for varied resolution of observations.

Comment: Also, satellites may be launched from different spacecraft and rendezvous on a particular path. This advance was made possible by Dave Folta, John Bristow, and Dave Quinn at NASA’s Goddard Space Flight Center (GSFC).[1]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed observation. As you expect, there are several Starlink satellite sightings here, and most get closed as duplicates. Also it's OK to post an answer to your own question.

Comment: These may also be of interest: from several years ago: [Can satellites travel in clusters?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/18001/7982) and in Space Exploration SE: [Are there any related groups of satellites that are in a line of 6 or more in a row?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/41770/12102) (also mentions the A-train)